# Adnroid Espresso: тестирование нескольких активити

Tags: java, android, espresso

Не могу понять как можно в одном тесте протестировать несколько `Activity` сразу.

**Например:**

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{
public MainActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}

 public void testTC_1_1(){
    onView(withId(R.id.createE)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.eventTitle)).perform(typeText("Test"), closeSoftKeyboard());
}
}
```

Так вот на строчке

```
onView(withId(R.id.createE)).perform(click());
```

тестируемый элемент находится на `MainActivity`. А на строчке

```
onView(withId(R.id.createE)).perform(typeText("Test"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

в совершенно другой активити и как следствие на этой строчке возникает ошибка:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: with id: com.metoo.android:id/eventTitle

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает ?